# Finite-difference approximation of the 2nd derivative operator matrix for a staggered grid

Tags: python, math, matrix, physics

I'm working on a computational physics assignment and I was looking for some help as I've got stuck!

The question is:

Write a function to create the finite-difference approximation of the 2nd derivative operator matrix for a staggered grid. Given the inputs N (the size of the matrix) and δx (the grid spacing), the function should return the tridiagonal matrix in the form of three arrays (a,b,c). Include the Neumann boundary conditions u0(−1) = u0(1) = 0 by modifiying specific elements of b

The aim of the assignment is to write a few functions in order to solve this non-linear elliptic equation:

u'' + 500*exp(−100*x^2) − u^3 = 0

In a practice class I wrote a more simple script for solving

u''(x) = f(x) = - exp(x) * (-2 + 2x + 5x^2 + x^3)

```
from pylab import *
from scipy import interpolate

def EllipticSolver(Nx):
    dx = 1.0/Nx
    pts = linspace(-dx/2.0,1.+dx/2.0,Nx+2)
    soln = zeros(Nx+2)
    rhs = zeros(Nx+2)
    rhs = -exp(pts)*(-2.0 + 2.*pts + 5.*pts**2 + pts**3)
    soln = tridiagonal2(soln,rhs,dx)
    return pts[1:-1], soln[1:-1]

def tridiagonal2(dat,d,dx):
    N = len(dat)
    print(N)
    dx2 = 1.0/(dx*dx)
    a = zeros(N)
    b = zeros(N)
    c = zeros(N)
    a[:] = dx2
    c[:] = dx2
    b[:] = -2.0*dx2

    b[1] = -1.0*dx2
    b[N-2] = -3.0*dx2

    c[1] = c[1]/b[1]
    d[1] = d[1]/b[1]
    for j in range(2,N-1):
        c[j] = c[j]/(b[j] - c[j-1]*a[j])
        d[j] = (d[j] - d[j-1]*a[j])/(b[j] - c[j-1]*a[j])

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(d)

    dat[N-2] = d[N-2]
    for j in range(N-3,0,-1):
        dat[j] = d[j] - c[j]*dat[j+1]

    return dat

x1, soln1 = EllipticSolver(100)
x2, soln2 = EllipticSolver(200)
x3, soln3 = EllipticSolver(400)

figure(1)
clf()
plot(x1,soln1,'r-')
plot(x2,soln2,'g-')

s2 = interpolate.interp1d(x2,soln2,'cubic')
soln2a = s2(x1)

s3 = interpolate.interp1d(x3,soln3,'cubic')
soln3a = s3(x2)

diff1 = soln1 - soln2a
diff2 = soln2 - soln3a

figure(2)
clf()
plot(x1,diff1,'r-')
plot(x2,4.*diff2,'g-')
```

So, Newton-Raphson method, discretise using finite-difference approximations of the derivatives

u'' = (u[i+1] + u[i-1] - 2u[i]) / dx2

So, the first thing I'm gonna have to do is set up some kind of array for u in order to whack it in a for loop and populate it using the above equation I don't know what 'u' should be here, I could use an array of zeros, but I need some values in order to get something for u''

In the example above, i create the rhs array using the staggered grid I produced called pts

Do I need to make another staggered grid for u, and then use that to make a RHS array:

```
rhs = zeros(N) 
rhs = (ui+1 + ui-1 - 2ui) / dx2
```

That wouldn't quite work but something along those lines...

Any pointers would be appreciated, I'm really unsure how to input this extra variable u properly

Thanks,
Leon

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the Newton-Raphson method is, as you say, it requires some initial value.  When I did this task at uni, I made the end-user input the initial guess.  For your particular case, you may wish to hard-code the initial guess.